# How to pass values in constructor using sigleton() in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics, typescript1.5

I have a doubt about how to pass the value in the constructor using a singleton class in typescript.

**mycode .ts**

```
import {singleton} from "tsyringe";

@singleton()
class Foo {
  constructor(data:string) 
{
this.data = data
}
}

// some other file
import "reflect-metadata";
import {container} from "tsyringe";
import {Foo} from "./foo";

const instance = container.resolve(Foo);
```

how to pass a value in the constructor using constainer .resolve function .any one gives the example code how to pass the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to inject a value into the constructor:

```
import {singleton} from "tsyringe";

@singleton()
class Foo {
  private str: string;
  constructor(@inject("SomeName") value: string) {
    this.str = value;
  }
}

// some other file
import "reflect-metadata";
import {container} from "tsyringe";
import {Foo} from "./foo";

const str = "test";

container.register("SomeName", { useValue: str });
const instance = container.resolve(Foo);
```

Comment: How would you proceed if the Foo wasn't singleton and you would like to supply different parameters to constructors for each instance?

Answer (score 0):

@user1762087 To answer your question, if you would like to supply different parameters to constructors for each instance you can do something like

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {container} from "tsyringe";
import {Foo} from "./foo";

const str = "test";

container.registerInstance("SomeName", { useValue: str });
const instance = container.resolve(Foo);

// to clear up instances you've registered with registerInstance()
container.clearInstances();
```